# How to write Custom Nant tasks of Nant tasks

Tags: task, nant

Hi I new to nant and am looking to make some kind of function/task that groups a bunch of regular nant tasks.

Basically I have 3 websites with web.config files that I need to write the connectionstring and imageDir values 2, only the file path changes

Currently I am looping through the a csv of file paths to accomplish this but would like to be able to pull the code out of the loop and make it a task/function/target or something. What is the best approach.

```
        <foreach item="String" in="${webConfig.includedFilePaths}" delim="," property="File.Path">
            <do>
                <xmlpoke
                    file="${File.Path}"
                    xpath="${connectionString.XPath}"
                    value="${connectionString.Value}" />
                <xmlpoke
                    file="${File.Path}"
                    xpath="${imageDir.XPath}"
                    value="${imageDir.Value}" />
            </do>
        </foreach>
```

I am hoping for something like:

```
<writeWebConfig file=${file.Path}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom nant task with a property like:

```
  <target name="UpdateConfig">
    <property name="config.filepath" value="" />
    <!-- Rest of the task code here -->
  </target>
```

And then you can call this task as many times as you want with the custom value of the property `config.filepath`. You can override the property value from command line using -D like:

```
-D:config.filepath=D:\TestWeb\web.config
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using a  target then just call it from another target using nant task

Comment: Ended up using a similar approach and use the nant task to exec the target from another target.